# How to Convert to Datetime YYYY-MM-DD HH:mi:ss

Tags: postgresql

I have a field where I need to populate `GETDATE()` with `YYYY-MM-DD HH-MI-SS` format.

Can anyone help me how to write the query in PostgreSQL?

I tried this in SQL Server and it worked. Not sure how to write in PostgreSQL.

```
SELECT
    SUBSTRING(CONVERT(VARCHAR(23),GETDATE(),112),1,4) + '-' +
    SUBSTRING(CONVERT(VARCHAR(23),getdate(),112),5,2) + '-' +
    SUBSTRING(CONVERT(VARCHAR(23),getdate(),112),7,2) + ' ' +
    CONVERT(VARCHAR(8), GETDATE(), 108)
```

Your help is appreciated.
Thank You 
Swathi.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `NOW()` with `TO_CHAR()` should do that for you:

```
SELECT TO_CHAR(NOW(),'YYYY-MM-DD HH-MI-SS');
```

Docs: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.5/static/functions-formatting.html

---

*To add some additional clarity...*

You have a table with a field that is of a datetime type. When you update the field, you must update it with a value of the same type.

If you want to return the values in that field in a particular format, you would use the `TO_CHAR()` in your `SELECT` statement.

For example:

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS mytable;
CREATE TABLE mytable (mydate TIMESTAMP);
INSERT INTO mytable VALUES (NOW() - INTERVAL '20 days');

-- Update with the appropriate type
UPDATE mytable SET mydate = NOW();

-- Select the date in the format you want
SELECT mydate, TO_CHAR(mydate,'YYYY-MM-DD HH-MI-SS') AS mydate_text FROM mytable;
```

OUTPUT:

[image]

Comment: My Datatype is timestamp for that field and when i using your query to update it gave me error. Column "date" is of type timestamp without timezone but expression is of type text hint:you will need to rewrite or cast the expression

Please let me know how do i fix it.
Thank you for the response Nicarus.

Comment: You need to cast it to the proper type. Generally it is as simple as `my_field::TIMESTAMP`, however, it must be a valid `TIMESTAMP`. Can you provide an example of the values in that field?

Comment: I dont have any value as of now. butThe value needs to look like 2016-07-14 12.07.40. I need to update the column in the table with YYYY-MM-DD HH.MM.SS format.
Sample data would look like 2016-07-14 12.07.40
Thank You :)

Comment: The answer I provided returns the equivalent of what you did in SQL Server. Are you now saying that you are referencing a field from a table for the date rather then `GETDATE()`/`NOW()`?

Comment: This works for me .I need to update the same results what i get for this select statement.
SELECT TO_CHAR(NOW(),'YYYY-MM-DD HH.MM.SS');
but when trying to update the field
Date datetime (datatype)
update table
set date =  TO_CHAR(NOW(),'YYYY-MM-DD HH.MM.SS');
It gave the above error.

Comment: (1) This is wrong: `YYYY-MM-DD HH.MM.SS`. To get the minute you need to use `MI` not `MM`, which gives you month. (2) If you are trying to update a field that is of the date type this will fail because `TO_CHAR` returns `TEXT`.

Comment: Got it my mistake i need hours minutes and seconds...Yes that is what happening now it is failing because it returns text where as my column data type is datetime.

Comment: You would not format a date, datetime, timestamp at all. Just update the field directly: `UPDATE mytable SET mydate = NOW() WHERE ...;`

Comment: If i do that i get this result 2016-07-14 12:25:05.358882-05
I want my results to be 2016-07-14 12:25:05

Comment: When you select the data from the table, that is when you should use the `TO_CHAR()`.